# Gamma like integral with power in exponent

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I came across an integral in my stat mech book of the form
$$\int_0^\infty x^{d-1}e^{x^s}dx$$
The book claims without proof that this is
$$\frac 1s\Gamma(d/s)$$
I tried doing a change of variables $y=x^s, dy=sx^{s-1}$ but I couldn't get my integrand to come out right. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: That is the correct substitution. But I assume you meant $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{d-1}e^{-x^{s}}\ dx$. Then note that on the interval, $y = x^{s} \implies x =y^{1/s} \implies dx = \frac{1}{s} y^{1/s-1} dy$.

Answer (score 2):

The integral you have provided is divergent
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{d-1}e^{x^s}dx.
$$
since your exponential term is positive.  For the integral to converge to the value you wrote, we must have a decaying exponential 
$$
I\equiv\int_0^\infty x^{d-1}e^{-x^s}dx=\frac{1}{s}\Gamma\big(\frac{d}{s}\big),\  \Re(s)>0, \ \Re(d)>0.
$$
For this we use your idea, $y=x^s$, $dy=s x^{s-1} dx$, $dx={s^{-1}dy x^{1-s}}$.  We also have $x=y^{1/s}$, $x^{d-1}=y^{(d-1)/s}$.  Thus we have
$$
I=\int_0^\infty y^{(d-1)/s}e^{-y}\frac{y^{(1-s)/s}}{s}dy=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty y^{d/s-1} e^{-y}dy.
$$
We can choose to define $\alpha\equiv d/s-1$ to obtain
$$
I=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty y^{\alpha} e^{-y} dy=\frac{1}{s}\Gamma(1+\alpha)=\frac{1}{s}\Gamma\big(\frac{d}{s}\big).
$$
This concludes the proof.